# Getting a new keystore file to sign apk in Android Studio with Automatic Key Signing

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, apk

I have an Android app in Android Studio and want to sign it to update and existing app to Google Play. So I am selecting Generate Signed Bundle but for some reason when I select my existing keystore no bundle or APK gets built. When I create a new keystore file then the APK gets build but of course I can't upload it to Play since the app already exists with another keystore file there.

I have automatic signing in Google Play enabled and was hoping to get a new keystore file from there. But all I get is an upload certificate. How do I use this upload certificate to sign my app in Android Studio?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain what happens when you try to build with the keystore? Any error messages / non-error messages? Where do you expect the APK to be?

Comment: After selecting the keystore file, entering the password and choosing release, I click finish and simply nothing happens, no process gets started, no error, nothing...

Comment: As a temporary workaround to release the apk you can follow this and execute the `assembleRelease`/`bundleRelease` task, this will create an apk in app/build/output folder. https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline#gradle_signing

Comment: Also it seems to be a problem with android studio... Can you try to close the project, delete the `.idea` folder and the `.iml` file?

Comment: @JensV I will try this, but I cannot find the .idea folder.